# Python - Select elements from matrix within range

Tags: python

I have a question regarding python and selecting elements within a range.

If I have a n x m matrix with n row and m columns, I have a defined range for each column (so I have m min and max values).

Now I want to select those rows, where all values are within the range.

Looking at the following example:

```
input = matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4],[5,6],[1,8]])
boundaries = matrix([[2,1],[8,5]])
#Note:
#col1min = 2
#col1max = 8
#col2min = 1
#col2max = 5
print(input)

desired_result = matrix([[3, 4]])
print(desired_result)
```

Here, 3 rows where discarded, because they contained values beyond the boundaries.

While I was able to get values within one range for a given array, I did not manage to solve this problem efficiently.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: explain your question in brief!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is more elegant solution, but i came to this:

```
def foo(data, boundaries):
    zipped_bounds = list(zip(*boundaries))
    output = []
    for item in data:
        for index, bound in enumerate(zipped_bounds):
            if not (bound[0] <= item[index] <= bound[1]):
                break
        else:
            output.append(item)
    return output

data = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 8]]
boundaries = [[2, 1], [8, 5]]
foo(data, boundaries)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4]]
```

And i know that there is not checking and raising exceptions if the sizes of arrays won't match each concrete size. I leave it OP to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data syntax is not correct `matrix([[],..])` so it needs to be restructured like this:

```
matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4],[5,6],[1,8]]
bounds = [[2,1],[8,5]]
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "efficient", but this solution is readable, computationally efficient, and modular:

```
# Test columns in row against column bounds or first bounds
def row_in_bounds(row, bounds):
    for ci, colVal in enumerate(row):
        bi = ci if len(bounds[0]) >= ci + 1 else 0
        if not bounds[1][bi] >= colVal >= bounds[0][bi]:
            return False
    return True

# Use a list comprehension to apply test to n rows
print ([r for r in matrix if row_in_bounds(r,bounds)])
>>>[[3, 4]]
```

First we create a reusable test function for rows accepting a list of bounds lists, tuples are probably more appropriate, but I stuck with list as per your specification.

Then apply the test to your matrix of n rows with a list comprehension. If n exceeds the bounds column index or the bounds column index is falsey use the first set of bounds provided.

Keeping the row iterator out of the row parser function allows you to do things like get min/max from the filtered elements as required.  This way you will not need to define a new function for every manipulation of the data required.